# How many times is a node rotated towards the root in a weight-balanced tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, binary-search-trees

In this [paper](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/%7Emehlhorn/ftp/mehlhorn22.pdf) they prove that the number of rotations after doing $n$ insertions or deletions to a weight-balanced tree is $O(n)$ (when starting from an empty tree).

What isn't clear to me though is how many times each node becomes the new root of a sub-tree after a single or double rotation takes place. Intuitively, I should expect this to be $O(1)$. Is this correct? How can this be shown?

Comment: $O(n)$ is $O(1)$ per insertion/deletion in the the amortized sense.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. But ned for a bound for individual nodes, or at least for paths from root to leaves and not in the amortized sense. Consider for example a case where a node has become the new root of a sub-tree $O\left(\frac{n}{2^k\log n}\right)$ times, where $k$ is the depth from the root. In this case, the total for each level in the tree would be $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$, and for the whole tree it would be $O(n)$. But if we consider a path from the root to leaves (which is what I'm interested in), we'd have a total of $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ and not $O(\log n)$.